# Typescript extend Request type from Express

Tags: typescript, express

I have NodeJs app with Express and Typescript. I'm trying to extend Request type from Express.

I've created index.d.ts with code bellow

```
import { User } from "models/user";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      currentUser: User
    }
  }
}
```

My code editor(I use VSCode) tell me that all is fine and autocomplete works great.
But in runtime typescript throw error

```
src/api/controllers/post.controller.ts:60:24 - error TS2339: Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
```

I found following code, that solved my problem

```
import { User } from 'models/user';
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  export interface Request {
    currentUser: User
  }
}
```

I had to copy this code in any file in my app and it works. But I don't understand why it works. Could anyone explain why it's happening and why first solution doesn't work?

I run my app with ts-node package. `ts-node ./src/index.ts`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "strict": true,                           
    "baseUrl": "./src",                       
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/@types",
      "./node_modules/@types",
    ],                       
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],                           
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Old question. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of express, you need to augment the `express-serve-static-core` module.

This is needed because now the Express object comes from there:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8fb0e959c2c7529b5fa4793a44b41b797ae671b9/types/express/index.d.ts#L19

Basically, use the following:

`@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
import { Express } from "express-serve-static-core";

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    myField?: string
  }
  interface Response {
    myField?: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should I write this declare? Because if I copy this code in index.d.ts it doesn't work. I think paste this code in entry point of app is bit messy.

Comment: with @types/express/index.d.ts also doesn't work :(

Comment: yes, I've tried `src/@types/express/index.d.ts`, `src/@types/index.d.ts` but doesn't work.

Comment: does not work, where are you supposed to put this declaration?